# How can I concatenate data from a web site into a data frame?

Tags: r

I'm trying to loop through 10 web pages and concatenate all the data into one single file.

Below is my non-working code.  How can I make this loop through all 10 pages, and append the data from the next page under the previous page?

```
library(XML)
library(plyr)

for(i in 1:10)
{
NHL <- htmlParse("http://www.hockey-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.cgi?month=1&day=i&year=2014")
class(NHL)
NHL.tables <- readHTMLTable(NHL,stringAsFactors = FALSE)
length(NHL.tables)
head(rbind.fill(NHL.tables))
write.csv(NHL.tables, file = "NHLData.csv")
}
```

I thought it was an issue of pulling the data, 1 URL at a time, and binding it together as I go, but it doesn't seem to work.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple.  Any thoughts?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you close. There's two tables per page, I took the biggest one to be the one you wanted...

```
library(XML)
df <- NULL
for(i in 1:10)
{
  url <- paste0("http://www.hockey-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.cgi?month=1&day=",
                i, "&year=2014")
  NHL <- htmlParse(url)
  NHL.tables <- readHTMLTable(NHL,stringAsFactors = FALSE)
  df <- rbind(df, NHL.tables[[1]])
}
write.csv(df, file = "NHLData.csv")
```

Comment: That works!  I knew it was something like that.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: Glad it helped, you were 80% of the way there.

Comment: 20% may be small, but extremely critical, especially if you're not an expert with this stuff.

Thanks again.